# How to change error response message of TokenObtainPairView?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

`TokenObtainPairView` class is used for token based authentication with jwt token.

Now I am getting an error message when I put wrong login details for user:

```
{
   "detail" : "No active account found with the given credentials"
}
```

I want to change it like:

```
{
   "detail" : "email or password is incorrect!"
}
```

Comment: Where is `TokenObtainPairView` imported from?

Comment: from rest_framework_simplejwt import views

Answer (score 1):

```python
# app/views.py

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView


class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

    default_error_messages = {
        'no_active_account': _('email or password is incorrect!')
    }


class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

Then, use `MyTokenObtainPairView` where `TokenObtainPairView` was used, e.g.:

```python
# app/urls.py

from app.views import MyTokenObtainPairView

urlpatterns = [
  ...
  path('auth/token/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view())
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create custom `LoginView` which accepts username and password and authenticate based on the given credentials then return access and refresh tokens if the user is authenticated.

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

def get_tokens_for_user(user):
   refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

   return {
     'refresh': str(refresh),
     'access': str(refresh.access_token),
   }

class LoginView(APIView):
   def post(self,request):
       username= request.data["username"]
       password = request.data["password"]

       user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
       if user:
           return Response(get_tokens_for_user(user))
       return Response({"error":"email or password isincorrect!"},status=status.HTTP_203_NON_AUTHORITATIVE_INFORMATION)
```